# Consider ($6-a)(6-b)(6-c)(6-d)(6-e)$ are $5$ distinct factors of $45.$ find value of $a+b+c+d+e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider $(6-a)(6-b)(6-c)(6-d)(6-e)$ are $5$ distinct factors of $45.$ Find the value of $a+b+c+d+e$.

Comment: Okay, so can you summarize the many tries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the factors of $45$ are $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 9, \pm 15, \pm 45$.

Now, we consider the largest absolute value factor.

It is not hard to see by Pigeonhole Principle, that the largest absolute value factor of $45$ for which we have $5$ distinct factors is $|5|$, so this factor can either be $5$ or $-5$.

Again, using Pigeonhole Principle we conclude that the largest absolute value factor of $9$ is $|3|$.

So, we get the remaining $4$ factors as $-3,-1,1,3$.

Now, as the product of $5$ numbers is positive, we conclude that the factors are $-3,-1,1,3,5$, which are all distinct.

If the $5$ factors are $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5$, then we can observe that $6-a=f_1 \Rightarrow a=6-f_1$ and similar results.

Thus, $a+b+c+d+e=(6 \cdot 5) -(5+3+1-1-3)=25$, as we can assign any factor to any variable and the sum will remain unchanged.

---

**Note:**

Largest absolute value factor of $45$ is $|45|$, ie. the factors could be $45$ or $-45$.

Answer (score 0):

$45
=9*5
=3*3*5
$
so to get
more distinct factors,
we need $1$ and
negative numbers.

For example,
$45
=3*-3*5*1*-1
=(6-3)*(6-9)*(6-1)*(6-5)*(6-7)
$
so the sum is
$3+9+1+5+7
=25
$.